# How to restrict an entire WordPress site to visitors, but the register and login page?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, plugins, restrictions

## Restrict Website, But Login and Register Page

---

#### I want my my entire WordPress site to be restricted to visitors, but I want the register and login page to be accessible (not restricted) to the visitors

Since my website is a members-only website, I want to restrict it's access so that visitors only see 2 pages, the login page and the register page.

I have tried multiple plugins to do exactly that but unfortunately for me, I haven't been able to find the right one. Some plugins redirect the entire website to one page while other plugins require custom redirection settings for each page to be separately added.

***What I want:-***

1. **Restrict entire WordPress website to visitors by redirection.**
2. **Do not restrict 2 pages, Login Page and Registration Page.**
3. **Redirect Users to Login Page and/or Register Page.**

There is an  option in my Login Page to view the Register Page.
I want both of these pages to be accessible to the visitor and the rest of the website to be inaccessible.

Comment: Just make your own plugin that uses a hook before the page outputs to the browser. It would be a 1/2 hr of work, especially if you are just hardcoding where the pages redirect to. It doesn't sound like you need any admin settings controls, so it really wouldn't be that hard. You only need to research the best hook then check if user is logged in, if not add a redirect to the page you want.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on [content and access restrictions](https://www.bynicolas.com/code/need-know-content-restriction-wordpress/). You can check it out. But @Stanimir's answer should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply redirect your users using `template_redirect` hook

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_users' );
function redirect_users( $template ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if ( !is_page( 'register page ID' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

You need to add register and login page IDs and login page URL in the function.

Comment: What would be the ID for default wp-login.php?

Comment: tried it, still not working, it just redirects to the login page for all pages including the register page.

Comment: Ok, I have changed my code above, so you need to add register page id.